# What folder(s)/files is safe to delete after compiling Python 3.8 from sources?

Tags: python, compiling, make

Sorry for the noob question but I can't seem to find a definitive answer on this. I have just successfully compiled Python 3.8 from sources, on Centos 7 (as a secondary python, I left python 2.7 as is).

The guide was pretty straightforward:

```
sudo yum install gcc openssl-devel bzip2-devel libffi-devel
cd /opt
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.0/Python-3.8.0.tgz
tar xzf Python-3.8.0.tgz
cd Python-3.8.0
sudo ./configure --enable-optimizations
sudo make altinstall
sudo rm Python-3.8.0.tgz
```

After compiling, apart from **deleting /opt/Python-3.8.0.tgz**, is it safe to also delete the **directory /opt/Python-3.8.0/** ? I am not sure from which directory python 3.8  actually runs from... I am interested to learn the generic way compiling works (not just for Python which I really brought up as an example).

Answer (score 0):

You can run `make clean` in order to remove the compiled file, due to the fact that is installed. Note, you have not enabled a lot of flag during the compilation. Be sure that ssl work, i think that your installation miss a lot of features.

Comment: What do you mean SSL works? What other features may be missing?

Comment: Run `./configure --help` in order to understand all the flag that can be enabled. If you don't have the `openssl` development library, ssl is not enabled.